# When is $k(X)$ algebraic over $k(Y)$ for a dominant morphism $f:X\rightarrow Y$ between varieties.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let $f:X\rightarrow Y$ be a dominant morphism between irreducible varieties over an algebraically closed field $k$.

When is $k(X)$ algebraic over $k(Y)$? Is there an if and only if criterion?
What if $f$ is even bijective?
From what I've found it should be enough that $f$ is finite. Is there a weaker criterion?

Comment: Of course it is enough that $f$ is integral. But probably this is not necessary.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg: Isn't generically finite enough?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$f$ being dominant implies that the corresponding ring homomorphism is injective. Thus we have an inclusion of integral domains over $k$, $A\hookrightarrow B$ and the function fields in question are the fraction fields of these domains. Obviously, we have $frac(A)\hookrightarrow frac(B)$.

Assuming that $A,B$ are *finitely generated* as algebras over $k$, we have a theorem which says that *the dimension of A is equal to the transcendence degree of frac(A) over k.* The same goes for $B$, of course. Clearly, the bigger field is algebraic over the smaller one if and only if both have the same transcendence degree over $k$, meaning $\dim A=\dim B$, or equivalently, $\dim X=\dim Y$.

Comment: Thank you for the nice answer. May I ask a follow up? Is it possible to have a bijective morphism of varieties with different dimension? So if $f$ is bijective is it always algebraic?

Comment: I don't think such a morphism is possible.